# Eigen3: How to access matrix coefficients in performance critical operations?

Tags: c++, optimization, compiler-optimization, eigen3

I am trying to optimize critical operations in C++ which rely on Eigen3. It is not clear for me what type of coefficient access operations would lead to runtime performance costs, or when would the compiler will make a good job. To try to pinpoint the source of my confusion I'm posting an example below implemented in a few different ways, together with some hypothesis for each.

Here a few more details:

- The matrix **M** will remain constant throughout most of the program
- **critical_function** is indeed called many times and this is why it is inlined

Could someone clarify which approach would be the best one in terms of performance? I might be confused on the impact cost of references, dereferencing, etc.

## Option 1: Directly accessing matrix coefficients

```
#include <Eigen/Dense>
class A{
    A(){
        // Assume M has the right numbers
    }

    // This function will be called many many times, inside loops
    inline void critical_function()
    {
        // Do many operations using M(1, 1), for example:
        double y = 1 / M(1, 1);
        // ... some more code using M(1, 1)
    }
private:
    Eigen::Matrix3d M;
};
```

**Hypothesis**:

- M(1,1) leads to constant dereferencing, incurring costs, as cycles will be added to computing an offset (this is not an array, but it is not clear how the compiler is managing this)

## Option 2: Creating a copy of the coefficient we care about

```
#include <Eigen/Dense>
class A{
    A(){
        // Assume M has the right numbers
        x = M(1, 1);
    }

    // This function will be called many many times, inside loops
    inline void critical_function()
    {
        // Do many operations using x, for example:
        double y = 1 / x;
        // ... some more code using x
    }
private:
    double x;
    Eigen::Matrix3d M;
};
```

**Hypothesis**:

- Accessing **x** generates less cycles than accessing **M(1, 1)**, thus it is preferable to Option 1.
- **x** indeed contains the same value as **M(1,1)** but carries the important risk of ensuring this data is duplicated, so this needs to be avoided for code maintenance.

## Option 3: Making use of references

```
#include <Eigen/Dense>
class A{
    A(){
        // Assume M has the right numbers
    }

    // This function will be called many many times, inside loops
    inline void critical_function()
    {
        auto & x = M(1, 1);
        // Do many operations using x, for example:
        double y = 1 / x;
        // ... some more code using x
    }
private:
    Eigen::Matrix3d M;
};
```

**Hypothesis**:

- Having a single reference **x** will generate less cycles than constantly referring to **M(1,1)** inside the scope of the function.
- This *potential* optimization has an impact only inside **critical_function**, but will not carry over in an external scope, such as a loop calling the function many times.

### Edit

The types were corrected to double (from int or float), to be consistent with Matrix3d.

Comment: You'll most likely won't see any difference cause `M(1, 1)` will be in the cache anyway. **Hypothesis:** you are trying to do premature optimization without knowing where your code spends the most time.

Comment: In other words: There is no 100% general answer to your questions. You will **always** have to profile your own code to find out what is best in **your** situation. In your case, it might make no difference at all because the compiler transforms things behind the scenes anyway. Here's a tip: One division costs one to two orders of magnitude more CPU time than what you are worrying about right now.

Comment: Thank you both for the answers. True that caching will have a positive impact, yet, accessing a coefficient while in cache still would generate more cycles that  accessing an scalar in cache (eg. a float)? Or not? I agree that profiling is the right approach and yes maybe I'm being picky and there are more impactfull operations, I'm just trying to understand well the concepts such that I can use the best practices. As I mentioned, critical_function is called many times. Could you please refer to the hypothesis that I stated and either confirm or correct my understanding?

Comment: Is `x` intentionally an `int` instead of `double` in option 2? Option 3 is unlikely making a difference, since `M(1,1)` will be simplified at compile time to something equivalent to `((double*)(this))[4]`

Comment: No, it was a mistake, thanks for pointing that out. I've corrected the code to be consistently doubles. Are operations with `x` (Option 2) faster than the access to `((double*)(this))[4]` (Option 1)?

Comment: `((double*)this)[4]` would be UB, don't do that. Also, the compiler might just inline `M(1, 1)` for you anyway, so until you look at the generated code and **measure**, you can't know for sure which option is faster. It's probably not 3 though.

Comment: The big takeaway here is don't focus on "micro-optimizations", that is what compilers are far better at doing. Only after you have completed your code and profiled to find any hot-spots would you need to look and see whether there is anything there you can do better that what the compiler has done (and the answer will usually be "No", optimization wasn't the issue, logic was...

Answer (score 0):

In short, don't bother and write `M(1,1)`.

If you're dealing with compile-time matrices like `Matrix3d` and indices known at compile-time, then the indexing computations involved in `M(1,1)` will be completely optimized away by any compiler. In other words, the two following snippets will generate the same assembly:

```
struct A {
  Matrix3d M;
  void foo() { double x = M(1,1); }
};

struct A {
  double a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i;
  void foo() { double x = e; }
};
```

So option 2 will be worse, and option 3 might also reduce performance because you introduce a pointer.